# Feature name needed

Tags: feature, list-template

I'm trying to run a permissions report with this [software](https://sppermissionanalyzer.codeplex.com/), but getting an error saying:

> ERROR: Feature 'ea6d4080-ea47-40d5-9f83-3a48f77b556d' for list
>   template '8585' is not installed in this farm.  The operation could
>   not be completed. 9/9/2015 7:54:51 AM ERROR: Stack Trace -    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder
>   sb)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()    at
>   PermissionReporting.DetailedPermissionHelper.ProcessWebs(ClientContext
>   context, Site site, Web CurrentWeb, SPSecurableObject&
>   CurrentSecurableObject)    at
>   PermissionReporting.DetailedPermissionHelper.ProcessWebs(ClientContext
>   context, Site site, Web CurrentWeb, SPSecurableObject&
>   CurrentSecurableObject)    at
>   PermissionReporting.DetailedPermissionHelper.GetStructure(String url,
>   BackgroundWorker bgw, Boolean AnalyzeListItems, Boolean
>   GetFullPermissionStructure, Boolean PreLoadPermissions, Boolean
>   LoadAllItems)    at
>   PermissionReporting.PermissionReport.ProcessSiteCollection(String Url)

So I need to identify what is Feature 'ea6d4080-ea47-40d5-9f83-3a48f77b556d' and a list template '8585'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using PowerShell and the next code:

```
Get-SPFeature | Sort -Property Scope,DisplayName | FT -GroupBy Scope DisplayName,Id > c:\file.txt
```

Greetings :)

Comment: Hi Marco,
Thanks alot!
Do you know how can I find a list template name as well?

Comment: Sure:
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://desarrollosp01/"
$web.ListTemplates > c:\file.txt